# Excel/VBA check if a whole row is present on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

A quick question. I am trying to detect if a row is present on another sheet. Simply said, if article+description+quantity+serial is present on another sheet, output a "Y" otherwise, output a "N". The problem I am facing with this, is the fact that the rows on the other sheet could be anywhere, there isn't a fixed position, only the column is known.

However, both the sheet on which the Y/N calculation has to be made, as the sheet on which the row should be searched/found, are dynamically generated by the means of VBA.

[Example of the tablestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp9rk.png)

Looking at the =COUNTIFS, I am actually wanting to have =COUNTIFS(A1;="Sheet2!A1:D100"), but the COUNTIFS functionality doesn't support the "range" lookup. I just want to search "ROW(1) in Sheet2!A1:D100"...

Does anyone know in which direction I should be looking?

Comment: Could that solve the problem, that when there are two identical rows with different serial numbers than the one I am looking for, that it could be that it gives me a false positive? For example, I am looking in sheet1 for a "gasket" serial number: "DSBB", but on sheet2 it only has two gaskets "AABB" and "AH65". Then it would give me a false positive. I absolutely have to do a whole row comparison, can't split it up.

Comment: Yes by your example it looks like that will work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Helper column which combines Number, Description & Serial.

Formula for Helper column:

`=$I3&"_"&$J3&"_"&$L3`

Formula for Instock column:

`=IF(COUNTIF($M$3:$M$6,$E3)>0,IF(SUMIF($M$3:$M$6,$E3,$K$3:$K$6)>=$C3,"Y","N"),"N")`

Instock formula checks if the value in the Helper column of Sheet1 appears in Helper column of sheet2. If appears, it is also check the sum of available parts satisfy the amount needed.

Output:

[image]

Comment: So many thanks! That was the missing puzzle piece. I used your solution with no problems, even the performance is "as good as to be expected". +1